# Getting column name as a result for question about row

Tags: r

I have a dataset called test

[image: test]

I need to write code for the following
q1. what does jim do the most and the  ANS will be 10 runs
q2 what are the three least things mike does and the  Answill be walks 6 runs 4 drives 4
q3 who travels furthest and the answer will be Jim 40

Comment: Are you sure of the answer to Q1? Looking at your data, it looks like Jim runs the most (10). Can you post your data as plain text?

Comment: Yes jim runs 10 sorry

Comment: walks runs cycles drives flys
paul 10 6 2 2 2
john 9 5 5 3 6
mike 6 4 8 4 8
jim 7 10 9 5 9

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an idea of how to put it into tidy format, and start to answer the questions.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
name = c("paul", "john", "mike", "jim"),
walks = c(10L, 9L, 6L, 7L),
runs = c(6L, 5L, 4L, 10L),
cycles = c(2L, 5L, 8L, 9L),
drives = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
flys = c(2L, 6L, 8L, 9L)
)
df

df <- df %>% gather(key = transport, value = "freq", walks:flys)
df

df %>% filter(name == "jim") %>%
  group_by(transport) %>% 
  arrange(desc(freq))
```

which gives you an output table like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   transport [5]
  name  transport  freq
  <chr> <chr>     <int>
1 jim   runs         10
2 jim   cycles        9
3 jim   flys          9
4 jim   walks         7
5 jim   drives        5
```

which lets you answer Q1.

Notice that `gather()` is used to make the data in the tidy format, like:

```
   name transport freq
1  paul     walks   10
2  john     walks    9
3  mike     walks    6
4   jim     walks    7
5  paul      runs    6
```

This looks like your homework, so it's probably better for you to figure out the rest for yourself, but this will get you on the right track.

Look into the functions in dplyr that you need.